# jQuery is undefined & unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this script that positions a div's background in proportion with the window size:

```
// JavaScript Document
var jQNC = jQuery.noConflict();

jQNC(document).ready( function () {
    setPunchMargin()
    jQNC(window).resize( function () {
        setPunchMargin();
    });
});

function setPunchMargin() {
    var windowWidth = jQNC(window).width();
    if (windowWidth <= 980) {
        var margin = 0;
    } else {
        var margin = Math.round((windowWidth - 980) / 2);
    }
    jQNC('.punch').css('background-position', margin + 'px 320px');
}
```

It works like a charm on my local machine, but when uploading it to the server i get jQuery is undefined and on the jquery library i get unexpected token error.

Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Thank you,
Radu.

Comment: Are you using a local copy of jQuery or a link to one on a CDN?

Comment: Can you post your script tag which includes jquery?  It could well be the path is wrong.

Comment: Could you supply a URL to this?

Comment: this is the url http://punchid.com/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are not uploading or referencing jQuery correctly. Try using an absolute reference to a Jquery CDN like: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

(where 1.5.1 is the version of Jquery you'd need).

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! But how do you explain why the same code works on my local machine and on the hosting server not?

Comment: It could be that you had the wrong path for your hosting server, or the file wasn't uploaded. Where is your CSS file in relation to your page on the server?

Answer (score 2):

You have jQuery included two times;

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://punchid.com/test/wp-content/themes/punch/js/jquery-1.6.1-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here;

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://punchid.com/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
```

The latter is an older version, I'd suggest removing that one from the code - But double check everything still works correctly afterwards.